# Multiple authentication in different databases

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to create a control panel that both simple users and admins can use. I have two databases. In admin_db i store the admins and in mysql_db i have the simple users. A user who is admin has the same username in admin_db and in mysql_db but probably different pass (for security and other reasons).

My concept is the following:

User logs in. If the username exists in the admin_db, give the option to login as admin too (probably add another button in the html). Otherwise show only the simple user options.

How can i achieve this? Currently i use the default `@login_required` but it checks in one db only, i cannot switch between databases.. 
How can i do something like the following:

```
def login(db=default, username=None):
    #check the authentication

......

logged_in = False
while not logged_in:
    if logged_in_mysql:
        if username in admin_db:
            show button 'login_as_admin'
        else:
            continue as normal
    else:
        login(mysql_db)

.....

if user_clicks_login_as_admin:
    login(admin_db, god)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none has answered, i have found a solution on my own, and posting it here for anyone having the same problem:

First of all i had 2 databases in my `settings.py`:

```
settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'myadmin',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'abc123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'mysql': {
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'abc123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

The concept was that a user in one db could also be in the admins db (or vice versa). To help django play with both databases at the same time i had to create a router which would point django to the right db for my login application. I created a `routers.py` in my project root folder:

```
routers.py

class LoginRouter(object):
    """
        Router for routing login operations to mysql db
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
            Point all operations on login models to mysql
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'login':
            return 'mysql'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
            Point all operations on login models to 'mysql'
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'login':
            return 'mysql'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
            Allow any relation if a both models in login app
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'login' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'login':
            return True
        # Allow if neither is login app
        elif 'mysql' not in [obj1._meta.app_label, obj2._meta.app_label]:
            return True
        return False

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'mysql' or model._meta.app_label == "login":
            return False # we're not using syncdb on our legacy database
        else: # but all other models/databases are fine
            return True
```

I also had to add the following line to my `settings.py`

`DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.LoginRouter']`

Now if you have different kind of authentication than classic django User authentication, you 'll have to create an authentication backend. I had to do this because my other db contained a field called name which was the "username" for the authentication. Notice that in my models i have many tables, that's why i'm calling dovecot.Users (i need the Users table here) So again in my root folder i created a `backends.py` and i added the following:

```
backends.py

#my custom model from my outer db
from login import models as dovecot
class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    """
    Email Authentication Backend

    Allows a user to sign in using an email/password pair rather than
    a username/password pair.
    """
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        """ Authenticate a user based on email address as the user name. """
        try:
            user = dovecot.Users.objects.get(name=username)
            if self.check_password(password, user):
                return user
        except dovecot.Users.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        """ Get a User object from the user_id. """
        try:
            return dovecot.Users.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except dovecot.Users.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

I then added to my `settings.py` the following (remember priority matters! when django succeds in a backend, it will not continue further. I will mention later how i checked in both dbs):

```
settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('backends.EmailAuthBackend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
```

So now i had created an app where django could check in both db to see if a user existed and authenticate them.. But i also wanted to see if a user in the mail_db had also admin rights.. So in my `views.py` in my login app i created a login_user:

```
from login.models import Users as dov
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def login_user(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    username, password = '', ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

        if username != '' and 'incorrect' not in state:
            db = []
            #check to see in how many dbs' is the specific user
            try:
                dov.objects.using('mysql').get(name=username)
                db.append('mysql')
            except models.ObjectDoesNotExist:
                #we are expecting such exception if user is not in db
                pass
            except:
                #todo return error page
                return render_to_response('auth.html', {'state': 'ERROR', 'username': username},
                                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            try:
                User.objects.using('default').get(username=username)
                db.append('admin')
                pass
            except models.ObjectDoesNotExist:
                #we are expecting such exception if user is not in db
                pass
            except:
                #todo return error page
                return render_to_response('auth.html', {'state': 'ERROR', 'username': username},
                                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            return render_to_response('home.html', {'db': '{}'.format(','.join(db)), 'user': user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return render_to_response('auth.html',{'state':state, 'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So now you login a user and you also check if that user exists in both dbs. If user exists on both, you can offer an admin login :)

Hope that helps anyone with similar problems. I searched a while on the internet and couldn't find a complete solution, so i decided to put this here for a future reference. I hope i haven't forgotten anything or made any mistakes